# parameterize UNIX statements

Tags: unix

I have a bunch of statements in UNIX that I want to loop to use parameterized value for their calculations.

```
more /var/xacct_data/xxxx/log_flattener/xxxx/logfile_current | grep " F " //E,I,D
**xxxx = mpay,mmg,tvr**


/var/xacct_data/faff/faff1/log_flattener/faffsnp1/ logfile_current | grep " F "         //E , I, D also
/var/xacct_data/faff/faff1/log_flattener/faffdbt1 /logfile_current | grep " F "       //E , I, D also
/var/xacct_data/faff/faff1/log_flattener/fafftxn1 /logfile_current | grep " F "             //E , I, D also
/var/xacct_data/faff/faff2/log_flattener/faffdbt2/ logfile_current | grep " F "       //E , I, D also
```

I want to store these paths in a file. Read from the file in a unix shell script. and run the unix commands on the above paths, while manipulating the above paths by substituting some values in the path..

For example, in the above code block, in the top most path. I want to replace the xxxx with the three values given. mpay, mmg and tvr. how do i go about it??

For every `grep " F "` I want to use E, I and D as parameters for the current path. how do i do it??

Answer (score 1):

The left part of the pipe seem truncated but for the grep side, I think you are looking for

```
   ... | grep " [FEID] "
```

Comment: there are no delimiters. wouldnt it treat FEID as a single string??

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve. Your code doesn't make sense as it is currently written.

Comment: Piping more to grep is useless. Your description and examples are inconsistent. xxxx doesn't match mpay,mmg,tvr in either position. There is an extra space in each line. Still unclear about what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. I won't write the entire script for you.

In bash, zsh, *etc*...

```
for directory in mpay mmg tvr; do
    for char in F E I D; do
        echo "Looking for lines containing ${char} in ${directory} directory..."
        grep "${char}" /var/xacct_data/${directory}/log_flattener/${directory}/logfile_current
    done
done
```

No need for `more` here. `grep` takes a filename as input.